# JIRA API: How to upload zip file as test result using Version and Test Cycle?

Tags: robotframework, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

I can update execution status by /rest/zapi/latest/execution/${ExecutionId}/execute, So I want to upload zip file as test result using Version and Test Cycle that Test Cycles are organised by version and project in Zephyr I try

```
${PathFile}    Set Variable  ${CURDIR}/Results/TC.zip
${file_data}  Get Binary File   ${PathFile}
${files}  Create Dictionary     file=${file_data}
${headers}    create dictionary    Content-Type=multipart/form-data    Authorization=Basic ${userpass}
create session    jira    ${jiraserver}  verify=True
${response}=    PUT On Session      alias=jira    url=/rest/zapi/latest/execution/${ExecutionId}/execute    headers=${headers}   files=${files}
```

But I got error "ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))"
Could someone share the steps and code that would allow me to upload the zip file?

Comment: requests's `files` kwarg seems to expect a open filehandle and you are you are trying to pass the actual contents of the data .. I'd try to pass that via `data`